# Comments At/Toward

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have a question about the preposition to use with "*comment*":

> 1. He made comments ***about*** her.
> 2. He made comments ***at*** her.
> 3. He made comments ***toward*** her.

"*About*" is definitely standard English.  But what about "*at*" and "*toward*"?

Answer (score 1):

If you said "he made comments at her" then it seems like you're saying he was making comments that were directed at her, maybe in a hostile sort of way. Like he's talking to someone else but spoke up a little louder to be sure she overheard him.

Using the word "toward" in the sentence instead of "at" would mean virtually the same thing.

However neither use is proper English. "At" is a preposition of time and place, neither of which is appropriate for the verb "comment". "Toward" is a preposition of movement, which again is not appropriate for "comment". [See this page for more info about types of prepositions.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/prepositions.htm)